# How can I reinstall all packages that were shipped by default on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: package-management, 16.10

I want to restore my installation back to default by reinstalling all packages that are shipped by default by Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: For example LibreOffice, terminal, etc. ?

Comment: Yes, everything to restore a virgin Ubuntu 16.10. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case that you want to **restore really everything to a "virgin"** Ubuntu 16.10 (as you said in the comment under your question), a fresh installation of the system might be the most easy way to go. Otherwise you would have to reinstall all the packages you want to have restored manually.

Comment: Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop wont restore anything back to original installed version, but only refresh packages belonging to the ubuntu-desktop metapackage to the current newest version.

Comment: @SorenA : You are right ! :) Thank you for your hint ! :) I removed that part to improve the answer. ! :)

Comment: I like the hint about ubuntu-desktop. Will that reinstall all packages that might have been manually removed by the user?

Comment: @orschiro Please try it out ... open a terminal and execute the following command : `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` ... afterwards logout and back in or reboot the operating system. But I assume it will not work, I have tested it by removing the default games and they were not reinstalled after running this command ... so either reinstall the packages manually or reinstall the system - just choose the solution which takes less time. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox That is just a meta-package, this won't reinstall its dependencies.